# Subject Verb Agreement: Singular and plural

Tags: verbs, subjects

Singular must go with singular and vice versa for plural.

However, Grammarly mentioned one sentence as correct and other as incorrect. Please check the below two sentences.

1. I usually post questions on this website.
2. I usually posts questions on this website.

Subject: I. (Singular)
Verb: post (this also need to be singular), so posts

However, "posts" is shown as incorrect on Grammarly. Why post? It is plural.

Comment: The [subject-verb agreement rules](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/modulesvagr.htm) apply to all personal pronouns except I and you, which, although SINGULAR, require PLURAL forms of verbs.

Comment: I often hear *you was* in American rap songs but I think it's non-standard. I don't think it's ungrammatical though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lucian Sava said in the comment, the first person singular pronoun *I* and the second person pronoun *you* are peculiar in that they have their own *subject-verb agreement* rules.

*I* always requires a plural verb although it's logically singular.

> I usually post (NOT <s>posts</s>) questions on this site.

But it has its own special form of *BE*, *am*.

> I am (NOT <s>are</s>) posting a question.

The past tense of *am*, however, is *was*—not *were*.<sup>1</sup>

> I was (NOT <s>were</s>) about to post a question.

*You*, on the other hand, always takes a plural verb regardless of whether it's plural or singular.

> You post (NOT <s>posts</s>) a question.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>It's possible to use *were*, but only when the proposition expressed is hypothetical or irrealis: e.g., *If I were to post a question, I would think twice because it might get downvoted*.</sub>